# What is the difference between installing tor from its homepage and from the command line?

Tags: command-line, software-installation, tor

Tor can be downloaded via their page, but it can also be installed via the terminal (and turned off and on through services tor start/stop).  My question is , what exactly is the difference between these two ?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!
Is your question about `tor` or `tor-browser`?
Also, please ask one question at a time and make title descriptive (e.g. "What is the difference between installing `tor` from its homepage and from the command line?")
I think you should add the tag "command-line" and remove "16.04", as this question is not specific to 16.04.

Comment: I was curious what the difference was between downloading tor via their website or from the terminal.  From their website you have a tor browser, from the terminal you can turn tor on and off (does this mean if tor is on and i load firefox , firefox is now using tor?